# Resque pending jobs on high - not processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I have redis and resque running. All installations were followed using github documentation. How come the process doesn't continue and just stays on pending job in a high priority? Please help.. Thanks!

Comment: We're going to need much more information to help diagnose. First, what does "stays on pending job in a high priority" mean? We need information, code, and steps that you've tried to help you.

Comment: sorry for a really, really late reply. been very busy for the past days. I have a worker that sends verification email to newly registered users to the site so that they can confirm their membership before they can fully access the site. I'm using this just on my local machine. "Stays on pending job in a high priority" means the sending of email is on queue - considered as a high priority task for Resque - but the email is actually not sending to the desired recipient. It's stuck in the queue. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @MoMo perhaps you can update your question with the actual code